# Unable to resolve object type 'tstzmultirange' on deployed database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, datagrip

I've just created a PostgreSQL database in Amazon RDS. I've connected to it from DataGrip and now I want to run a migration SQL script.

I get this error when I try:

> Unable to resolve object type 'tstzmultirange'

I have googled [tstzmultirange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and it is a built-in PostgreSQL data type. It might be new to PostgreSQL 14, but my RDS database is running PostgreSQL 14 so why is the script giving that error?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That error message "unable to resolve" is not from PostgreSQL. Amazon must have hacked up the server here. You'll have to ask them. I'll remove the PostgreSQL tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multirange types are quite new in PostgreSQL, so we have [task in progress](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15014) for complete support of these types in IDE.

Comment: Oh dear. For now, what do you think I should do? Search for another SQL client that has that?

Comment: No, just disregard this warning, SQL query will run fine in fact.

Comment: You can also try EAP for 2022.1 where built-in multi-rabge types are supported https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/nextversion/